# The word for the gain in a race acquired by taking the inside track

Tags: single-word-requests

When traveling around a turn, the inside track has the shorter path than the outside track. The racer who takes the inside track (car, runner, cyclist) will gain a lead compared to the racer who takes the outside track.

What is the word that describes this gain?

```
Chris had to over come the <WORD> gained by Sara as he passed her on the turn.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chris had to over come the ***inside advantage*** gained by Sara as he passed her on the turn.

Comment: I do reckon this be the term.

Answer (score 2):

I might go with "geodesic gain" where ***geodesic*** means "of, relating to, or denoting the shortest possible line between two points on a sphere or other curved surface" ([here](https://www.google.com/#q=geodesic))

- "Chris had to overcome the geodesic gain accrued by Sara on the turn."